# hash table implementation code fails to run

Tags: c, algorithm

I have developed the below hash table implementation code, but it fails to execute while trying to insert key,value pair.

I am very new to this concept and trying hard to fix this one.Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
        #include <stdlib.h>
        #include <stdio.h>
        #include <limits.h>
        #include <string.h>
        #include<conio.h>

        struct entry_s {
            char *key;
            char *value;
            struct entry_s *next;
        };

        typedef struct entry_s entry_t;

        struct hashtable_s {
            int size;
            struct entry_s **table; 
        };

        typedef struct hashtable_s hashtable_t;


        /* Create a new hashtable. */
        hashtable_t *ht_create( int size ) {

            hashtable_t *hashtable = NULL;
            int i;

            if( size < 1 ) return NULL;

            /* Allocate the table itself. */
            if( ( hashtable = malloc( sizeof( hashtable_t ) ) ) == NULL ) {
                return NULL;
            }

            /* Allocate pointers to the head nodes. */
            if( ( hashtable->table = malloc( sizeof( entry_t * ) * size ) ) == NULL ) {
                return NULL;
            }
            for( i = 0; i < size; i++ ) {
                hashtable->table[i] = NULL;
            }

            hashtable->size = size;

            return hashtable;   
        }

        /* Hash a string for a particular hash table. */
        int ht_hash( hashtable_t *hashtable, char *key ) {

            unsigned long int hashval=0;
            int i = 0;

            /* Convert our string to an integer */
            while( hashval < ULONG_MAX && i < strlen( key ) ) {
                hashval = hashval << 8;
                hashval += key[ i ];
                i++;
            }

            return hashval % hashtable->size;
        }

        /* Create a key-value pair. */
        entry_t *ht_newpair( char *key, char *value ) {
            entry_t *newpair=NULL;

            if( ( newpair == malloc( sizeof( entry_t ) ) ) == NULL ) {
                return NULL;
            }

            if( ( newpair->key = _strdup( key ) ) == NULL ) {
                return NULL;
            }

            if( ( newpair->value = _strdup( value ) ) == NULL ) {
                return NULL;
            }

            newpair->next = NULL;

            return newpair;
        }

        /* Insert a key-value pair into a hash table. */
        void ht_set( hashtable_t *hashtable, char *key, char *value ) {
            int bin = 0;
            entry_t *newpair = NULL;
            entry_t *next = NULL;
            entry_t *last = NULL;

            bin = ht_hash( hashtable, key );

            next = hashtable->table[ bin ];

            while( next != NULL && next->key != NULL && strcmp( key, next->key ) > 0 ) {
                last = next;
                next = next->next;
            }

            /* There's already a pair.  Let's replace that string. */
            if( next != NULL && next->key != NULL && strcmp( key, next->key ) == 0 ) {

                free( next->value );
                next->value = _strdup( value );

            /* Nope, could't find it.  Time to grow a pair. */
            } else {
                newpair = ht_newpair( key, value );

                /* We're at the start of the linked list in this bin. */
                if( next == hashtable->table[ bin ] ) {
                    newpair->next = next;
                    hashtable->table[ bin ] = newpair;

                /* We're at the end of the linked list in this bin. */
                } else if ( next == NULL ) {
                    last->next = newpair;

                /* We're in the middle of the list. */
                } else  {
                    newpair->next = next;
                    last->next = newpair;
                }
            }
        }

        /* Retrieve a key-value pair from a hash table. */
        char *ht_get( hashtable_t *hashtable, char *key ) {
            int bin = 0;
            entry_t *pair;

            bin = ht_hash( hashtable, key );

            /* Step through the bin, looking for our value. */
            pair = hashtable->table[ bin ];
            while( pair != NULL && pair->key != NULL && strcmp( key, pair->key ) > 0 ) {
                pair = pair->next;
            }

            /* Did we actually find anything? */
            if( pair == NULL || pair->key == NULL || strcmp( key, pair->key ) != 0 ) {
                return NULL;

            } else {
                return pair->value;
            }

        }


        int main( int argc, char **argv ) {

            hashtable_t *hashtable = ht_create( 65536 );

            ht_set( hashtable, "key1", "john" );
            ht_set( hashtable, "key2", "kris" );
            ht_set( hashtable, "key3", "ricky" );
            ht_set( hashtable, "key4", "mike" );

            printf( "%s\n", ht_get( hashtable, "key1" ) );
            printf( "%s\n", ht_get( hashtable, "key2" ) );
            printf( "%s\n", ht_get( hashtable, "key3" ) );
            printf( "%s\n", ht_get( hashtable, "key4" ) );

            return 0;
        }
```

Comment: `newpair == malloc(...)` looks suspect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change

`newpair == malloc( sizeof( entry_t ) )` to

`newpair = malloc( sizeof( entry_t ) )`

in `ht_newpair`